# Magento CSS Wrap Wrong display

Tags: theme, catalog, css

[Web Page](http://corkandbarrelstore.com/wines/2010-fontes-da-cunha-mondeco-red-dao.html/)

I've been trying to correct that wrap unssuccesfully, it's just messed with the cloud-zoom... Im using a custom theme i've bought and even with the original style.css the problem persists. Thanks in advance!

Problem:

[Problem http://puu.sh/lnWPF/caffe66c5a.jpg](http://puu.sh/lnWPF/caffe66c5a.jpg)

Comment: Have you got a url for this page? Quite hard to debug from a picture

Comment: "Web Page" at the top is the URL , its not very easy to see though, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.product-image` class that encloses the image (and has the border) is fixed at 120px on line 30 of [this](http://corkandbarrelstore.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/magestore/featuredproduct.css) css file.

Try adding this line to that file to override the width setting in this situation:

```
.product-box-customs .product-image { width: auto; }
```

Comment: This worked correctly. I realized the problem was due to an extension called "featured product" and by disabling it the problem was no more. Though your fix would have worked. Thanks a lot!